# Making Div Appear when clicking Ok On Confirm Dialog

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
<form method="GET">
    <input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name">
    <input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="I'm ready!">
</form>
<br>
<script>
function clicked() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    return confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!');
}
</script>
```

Is it possible to make text appear (**not on an alert box**) when the user clicks ok on the alert. In addition, when the text appears, is it possible to make the form fade out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its very simple, confirm return **true** or **false** on the basis of whether you are clicking **"Yes"** or **"No"**,
So when you get true make the form **display none** and put text in container,

Js Code:

```
function clicked() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
if(confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!'))
{
    document.getElementById('nameDiv').innerHTML = 'Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!';
    document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.display = "none";
}

}
```

Js Fiddle : [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hehbw1vL/)

Comment: Great! That seems to of done the trick. Just one question, if I then wanted to make another form appear after closing mainDiv, how would I do that?

Comment: for that you can do this, document.getElementById('yourDiv').style.display = "block";

Comment: Thanks again Learning. Sorry for the constant questions (I'm quite new to JavaScript). How would I make the id 'yourDiv' only appear when the user presses ok in the alert?

Comment: Not an issue, write the above mentioned code in if block.

Comment: What do you mean by 'in if block'?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
    function clicked() {
    var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    var r = confirm('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!');
    if (r==true)
      { 
      // Code to fadeOut form comes here: 
      // jquery:
      // $("form").fadeOut();
      // Pure JS: ( hides the form with ID "myform" )
      // document.getElementById("myform").style.display="none";
      // document.getElementById("id of thanks message").style.display="inline";
      }
    return r; // If you want to stay in this page just return false not r
}
</script>
```

Besides I suggest attaching the function to **form submit** not to **button click**. Because user may submit the form by pressing Enter.

Comment: He's not using jQuery.

Comment: You right. But the question is about event after confirmation not *how to fadeout*

Comment: You have to write your own fade Out function. I used jquery and you can also use if you have jquery. Please check edited answer again.

Comment: Since this 'fading out' stuff seems to be complicated, is there a way to just make it vanish, then text appear?

Comment: I have updated my answer using both jquery and pure JS. Good luck

Comment: Hi Ali, I seem to have discovered an issue with your pure javascript code. When the alert pops-up and the user clicks ok, the form vanishes but then returns.

Comment: Actually Yes! because your form is being submitted and the page is being refreshed! If you want to prevent submitting your form, always return false instead of returning **r**

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to your form as a handler for JQuery. Then add a placeholder element (in this case it is #reply-user) to output your message (greeting) to the user. The placeholder is a way you can bypass an alert popup.

```
<form id="your-form" method="GET">
<input type="text" class="form" name="name" placeholder="Your name here!" id="name">
<input type="submit" onclick="return clicked();" value="I'm ready!">
</form>
<h3 id="reply-user"></h3>
<br>

<script>
function clicked() {
var name = document.getElementById('name').value;
$('#your-form').fadeOut();
$('#reply-user').append('Hello ' + name + ', great to see you!');
}
</script>
```